# How to show 0 value infomation in treemap highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

Hi I would like to show the 0 values information in the treemap highcharts. but in the example if we give value 0, its not showing that infomation.

```
     data: [{name: 'A',value: 0,colorValue: 1},
            {name: 'B',value: 6,colorValue: 2}, 
            {name: 'C',value: 4,colorValue: 3}];
```

In the above data, treemap is showing B and C values. A value is 0, so A is not showing in the chart. I need to show that information also. how can i show that in treemap chart.

please check the [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fk7p5x26/1/)

thanks

Comment: How do you want to show 0 in the chart? It does not make sense to make a box for a non-existent value. Please clarify, with illustrations if possible what you are after.

Comment: I have additional data name and views etc, I just want to show that in name and value 0 in the chart,is possible to show name and value 0

Comment: Treemap cells dimensions are based on theire values, so 0 mean nothing to display. The heatmap could display cell with 0 but they have all the same size [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/h0Lfahed/)

Comment: thanks for the clarifications Core972, wil use heatmap

Comment: Is this issue solved?

Comment: No, but i am not showing 0 values in the chart

Answer (score 1):

This is a **very ugly workaround**, but I managed to achieve this by using another property to store my real value while setting the treemap value plus 1.

Then I used `pointFormat` to display the correct value.

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.myValue}'
},
data: [
    {name: 'A', value: valueA + 1, myValue: valueA, colorValue: 1},
    {name: 'B', value: valueB + 1, myValue: valueB, colorValue: 2}, 
    {name: 'C', value: valueC + 1, myValue: valueC, colorValue: 3}]
},
```

Comment: Yeah... I know... This doesn't make sense to me either, but I'm not the one who talks with the users.